# How do I change the default indentation of 'if' for Common Lisp and Scheme?

Tags: indentation, common-lisp, scheme

When I am using `(setq lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function)`, the `if`s are indented like this:

```lisp
(if x
    y
    z)
```

For Scheme, `(setq lisp-indent-function 'scheme-indent-function)` also produces the same indentation as above.

I would prefer `if`s to be indented like this instead:

```lisp
(if x
  y
  z)
```

Is there a way to customize `common-lisp-indent-function` and `scheme-indent-function` such that `if`s will be indented by two spaces instead of being aligned with the predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. There are a few customization suggestions for `common-lisp-indent-function` inside cl-indent.el. The same mechanism is used for `scheme-indent-function`. Place the following in your init file:

```
(put 'if 'scheme-indent-function 1)
```

To achieve the following indentation in a Scheme buffer:

```
(if foo
  bar
  baz)
```